# How can I get salt to stick better to buttered or oiled popcorn?

Tags: salt, popcorn

I make popcorn with butter or olive oil, but still when I add salt, especially kosher salt or coarse sea salt, it won't stick. Is there anything I can do to get it to adhere better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to have the finest possible salt. One way to do this is to take any salt you like, and grind it fine in a mortar and pestle. This just takes a few seconds, and then you can customize to a particular sea salt you enjoy and avoid the need to buy a special popcorn salt. A rotating action in the mortar and pestle (as opposed to pounding) is most efficient for grinding salt.

Answer (score 3):

Grind the salt in a small spice grinder or food processor until it is a powder.