# How do I get seasoning to stick to home-popped popcorn?

Tags: seasoning, popcorn

I've been popping my own corn and I want to season it with salt, but when I sprinkle it over the popcorn it just ends up at the bottom of the bowl without taking to the popcorn. How could I get the seasoning to stick to the popcorn?

Comment: Almost-duplicate (that person was already using oil): http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/how-can-i-get-salt-to-stick-better-to-buttered-or-oiled-popcorn

Answer (score 9):

If you want dry seasonings to stick to popcorn, you will probably need to add a liquid to adhere them with. You could try adding butter or oil to your popcorn while it is hot, then adding the salt and tossing it together. If you're avoiding extra fat, a few spritzes of a non-stick spray (like Pam) might do the trick without adding significant fat.

Comment: I bought some expensive organic olive oil spray and thoroughly sprayed the popcorn but my nutritional yeast didn't really stick despite being ground fine. I saw a You Tube of someone called Mareko (I think) advocating Tabasco sauce or lime juice. Will try that next. Interested in hearing from any one who has done that.

Comment: I use one of the misting pump sprayers filled w/ olive oil.  A little spritz, sprinkle with popcorn salt, maybe a second spritz if I made a large batch, then toss some more.  The salt that doesn't stick falls through to the bowl, so it's the oil that actually affects how much ends up on the popcorn.  And if you can't find popcorn salt, look for pickling salt, which is another fine grind (but also iodine free)

Answer (score 6):

I air pop my popcorn and then I spray it with [Dr. Bragg Liquid Aminos](http://bragg.com/products/bragg-liquid-aminos-soy-alternative.html).  It has a salty flavor and if you spray it lightly it doesn't make the popcorn soggy.

If all you want is the salty flavor then this will do it but it also has the added advantage of allowing other spices to stick as well.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, as Sourd'oh says, to using some fat as glue.  Water will also work if you don't want calories, but will soften the popcorn somewhat.

Use popcorn salt.  This is salt that is very, very fine, so that it sticks more easily to popcorn.

Additionally, applying the salt immediately after popping when the popcorn is very hot will help.

Comment: I had wondered if you could perhaps mist the popcorn with a brine while it's still hot to minimize the sogginess. Time for experiments!

Comment: Be careful when you use the ground salt. My family and I ground up the salt into a fine powder to where it resemble confectioners sugar and poured it on the hot popcorn. It sticks but when you eat the popcorn, you also inhale the tiny salty particles and cough up a storm. We continue eating but it is annoying and leaves a slightly salty feeling in your throat as if you had stayed outdoors on a boat for too long.

Answer (score 2):

Put the salt in a spice grinder (such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005AL9D))! My grinder has several options for granule size. Unfortunately, it has no markings or logos on it so I can't tell you what the exact type it is else I'd highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not liquid. The problem is the size of the salt. You have to grind the salt. If you don't have a spice grinder, (I use a mortal & pestle) you can put a cup of salt in a blender :) and use it in the future.

Comment: This is already in the Aug 2013 answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add the salt to the oil while it is heating up - or otherwise mix with the kernels before throwing them into the oil?  I have done this both with sugar and salt and it works well for me (and the salt does not appear to burn or damage the saucepan...  If you shake everything up (as you should do) while cooking, then the popcorn gets evenly coated.  However, no-one else seems to suggest this, so there may be something I am not considering...