# When to season popcorn?

Tags: microwave, popcorn

I enjoy snacking on popcorn, and i recently found out you can pop it without losing flavour in the microwave.

I have always seasoned my popcorn after popping, but i am not really sure what is best with the microwave. Would it be to salt and pepper my snack before, after, or both?

Answer (score 3):

I worked three years in a movie theater in my early twenties.  The butter is tricky.  We would microwave it then separate the water from it.  If the water is still in the butter and put on the popcorn the water will make the popped corn soggy and give off an unappealing smell.  We would usually pour it off to separate them but that works best when a large amount is used.  A small amount could be warmed in a pan long enough to evaporate the water.  then alas put it on the finished popped corn.  Time it so both the corn and butter are warm at the same time.  Don't cover the popped corn with the idea of keeping it warm; There is still a little moisture in the popped corn and will make your treat less crispy.
If dried spices are the idea then try infusing the spice with the butter after the water is removed.  Don't get the mixture any warmer than warm.  You don't want the spices getting browned.  If the spices were put in the kettle while popping the corn they would be too toasted.

Answer (score 3):

I like to season immediately after I take it out of the microwave. At that point, there is a still a little bit of steam/moisture (admittedly, not much) in with the popped kernels, and that moisture helps whatever seasoning powder you use adhere to the kernel.

Also, if you aren't doing so already, consider using a salt specific for popcorn, a.k.a. "popcorn salt." It has a finer grind than table salt and that helps it stick the kernels better. Google it, there are many brands. I use one with cheese flavor in it.

This Q also has some pointers [How do I get seasoning to stick to home-popped popcorn?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35762/how-do-i-get-seasoning-to-stick-to-home-popped-popcorn)

Answer (score -3):

After, because then the surface is big enough to absorb the taste.

May I also suggest using organically grown corn, have a look at this article why:
http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/time-to-rethink-corn/

Comment: any reasons why this is getting minus points? Not season after popping because of surface?

Comment: Down votes are probably due to the second paragraph, which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Ah yes that must be it. ;-) Bit silly though, considering it was the right answer (and the second paragraph I added obviously isolated from the answer, and is true as well, very very true...). Ok, I will take the minus for that. Important enough,

Comment: Someone has to do it....allright, I changed it Stephie, thanks.

Comment: good man, glad to hear that!

Comment: Popcorn (whether organic or not) isn't GMO.

Comment: How do you know this?